# TFS 2015 alerts

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, tfs-alerts

I want to assign alerts for my team project as followed:
1. Every build that failed will trigger an email notification for the last developer that committed a change.
In additional send the same email to the code reviewer.

I only found that a failed build will sent to all team members an email or to me and I cant change the "Sent To" field (its disabled and I'm administrator user)

2. Another issue I encountered is that when a build failed the email I get states that there is 0 errors and 0 warnings. How Come?

It's supposed to be fairly easy to configure but didnt managed to get the email right.
Can someone assist here?

This is the email I get, a failed build with 0 errors, when entering the build url I can see the where the build has failed but how can I know it from the email???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the "sent to" filed, however you can choose the name of the team member from the drop down list, or type the name in the search box.

- Choose the name of the team member from the drop down list, or type
  the name in the search box.

[image]

For the people who trigger the build (which one need to be reviewed), he can specify the coder reviewer and add a build fail alert, add the filter `request by = [Me]`

[image]

As for question 2, there is 0 errors and 0 warnings.Which build are you using? vNext or xaml? And did you mean the build actually failed with errors but it's not reflected in the email.

---

**Update**

The errors and error message should be contained in the e-mail just as below picture.
[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm using vNExt build and yes, the email doesn't reflects the build errors so developers need to open the portal build output to view the errors.

Comment: The errors and error message should be contained in the e-mail just as above picture. Did this occurs for all your build definitions or just that one?

Comment: Not sure if i did something or not but I can see the error now. In old failed build email I got a failed build with 0 erros

Comment: Seems to be a cache issue.

Comment: guess I left it too soon. :) I edited the original message and upload a screen shot. are you familiar with that?